# Finding the vector coordinates a third of the way between two other vectors

Tags: vectors

Sorry if this seems a simple question. I'm trying to work out a specific position between two vectors that are using world coordinates 'Loc1' and 'Loc2'.

I didn't have any trouble finding a position half way, which was simply (Loc1 + Loc2) * 0.5

But I'm trying to find the vector position a third of the way between them. Dividing or multiplying by 0.3 will give me a position not relative to either of them.

Unfortunately I haven't built up the reputation to embed pictures in my posts but I have drawn an example of what I mean here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kux6Z.png

Thanks for any help you might have

Jim

Comment: The line through the two vectors ${\bf L}_1$ and ${\bf L}_2$ can be parameterized by ${\bf L}(t) := (1 - t){\bf L}_1 + t{\bf L}_2$. Which values of $t$ correspond to the two endpoints? Which value corresponds to the point one third of the way between the vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be $f$ of the way from $\vec{x}$ to $\vec{y}$, use $$f\vec{y} + (1-f) \vec{x}$$ where $0 \le f \le 1$.